# Can I provide access to an Android App without unlocking the Lockscreen?

Tags: java, android, locking

Is it possible to develop an Andriod App which can be launched directly from the Lock screen without unlocking the phone (like the Camera app)?

Comment: Not sure about _launching_ an app, but an app which is already running can interact via the login screen, q.v. the various messaging apps such as Skype and WhatsApp.

Comment: https://www.techzac.com/use-whatsapp-without-unlocking-android/ Did you mean something like this?

Comment: It was possible to put [widgets](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) on lock screen on API versions 17-20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Not atleast if you are not using a Custom Rom. Android by default supports only the Camera App and the Emergency dialer in the Lock Screen. Any other Apps cannot be launched without unlocking the Phone due to Security and Privacy reasons.

Even ,in the Camera App, you cannot view the Previous taken pictures or the Gallery. Camera App was decided to be allowed a launch for emergency reasons like for some visual proof collection and such things,even if the phone does not belong to you.

Comment: Okay. But can I launch an Call Intent from the notification (when the user taps on it from the Lock screen) of my running App , without unlocking my phone ?

Comment: This isn't true, at least in Android 12 (and probably Android 11 and prior). Tasker is able to display interactive 'Scenes' while the device is locked. I'm not sure exactly how, but it may be the use of the permission to run the foreground service.

Also see this question: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216906/access-apps-without-unlocking